# Android How to Inject application into class where context is not present?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, android-lifecycle, android-context

I have an android application

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp extends Application {

    static MyApp app;

    static MyApp getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        app = this;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to use it inside a class

```
class AppStateUsingClass {
  public void mymethod() {
   MyApp app = MyApp.getApp();
   //use app
  }
}
```

Now I can access the app where I don't have the context but I am not sure if its correct way of doing.
My understanding is that the application life cycle is through out app start and stop, therefore its lives as a Singleton so it shall be fine but not sure.

Isn't there any simpler cleaner API to access app, I have app state in **MyApp** class which I would like to access where context is absent?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated?

Comment: What are you needing to do? What is the problem of using [ApplicationContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)? Also, never count on static in Android, the application can be destroyed (there is no onDestroy for that context). Never put Context into static as well.

Comment: I am trying to get the Application inside class where context is not available. added a class in question to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a fairly common pattern, and shouldn't really cause problems.

The application class can be treated as a singleton that is alive as long as any part of your application is alive.

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) specifically state that this class is used to hold application state.

However, depending your actual design, the kind of state information you want to hold and where you want to access it, you may want to create your own singleton, independent of the application class and use that.

Or, you may want to initialize your `AppStateUsingClass` with a state object passed in the constructor.

This is a design decision, and if you want more opinions on it, create a working code example and post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com